# Why a numpy array is still a <class 'numpy.ndarray'> when it has a "sympy.core.symbol.Symbol" inside?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types, sympy

When I declare a symbol and an array like these

```
t  = symbols('t')
v1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ]])

print( type(v1) )
```

and I put a symbol inside the array

```
v2 = v1.dot(t)

print( type(v2) )
```

Question 1: Why is v2 still a numpy.ndarray if now it has a symbol inside?

When I try to integrate this array I cannot do it

```
# I1 = integrate( v2 , t ) # this cannot be integrate because...

# AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_poly'
```

Then, I have to do this

```
v3 = smp.Matrix( v2 )

I2 = integrate( v3 , t )
```

Question 2:

Is there another way to integrate v2, without to change it in a sympy Matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sympy` and `numpy` are not integrated.  `sympy` objects work in arrays to the extent that they can be treated as 'objects', and have the appropriate methods.  Otherwise `numpy` does not do anything special with `sympy` objects.

In an `isympy` session:

```
In [200]: t                                                                                          
Out[200]: t

In [201]: tau                                                                                        
Out[201]: τ
```

An array with symbols will be `object` dtype.  That's like a list, with references to those numbers and objects.  It's not a special array dtype:

```
In [202]: arr = np.array([1,2,tau,t])                                                                

In [203]: arr                                                                                        
Out[203]: array([1, 2, tau, t], dtype=object)
```

`np.dot` works because the symbols can be added and multiplied:

```
In [204]: np.dot(arr,arr)                                                                            
Out[204]: 
 2    2    
t  + τ  + 5

In [205]: type(_)                                                                                    
Out[205]: sympy.core.add.Add
```

`dot` with two matching 1d arrays returns a "scalar", in this case a `sympy` object.

Same for a dot with matching size list of numbers:

```
In [206]: np.dot([1,2,3,4],arr)                                                                      
Out[206]: 4⋅t + 3⋅τ + 5

In [207]: type(_)                                                                                    
Out[207]: sympy.core.add.Add
```

But dot of the 3 element list with scalar `tau` produces an array:

```
In [208]: np.array([1,2,3]).dot(tau)                                                                 
Out[208]: array([tau, 2*tau, 3*tau], dtype=object)
```

dot of a (3,4) with (4,) produces a (3,) array:

```
In [210]: np.ones((3,4),int).dot(arr)                                                                
Out[210]: array([t + tau + 3, t + tau + 3, t + tau + 3], dtype=object)
```

`sympy` also does not "know" about `numpy`, so it shouldn't be surprising that `integrate(ndarray, ...)` does not work.

The error `# AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_poly'` indicates that the array has been converted into an `ImmutableDenseNDimArray` sympy object.  Without getting into details, that apparently is the wrong type of sympy object for this purpose.

With your `v2`:

```
In [220]: v2                                                                                         
Out[220]: array([[t, 2*t, 3*t, 4*t, 5*t]], dtype=object)
    
In [222]: Matrix(v2)                                                                                 
Out[222]: [t  2⋅t  3⋅t  4⋅t  5⋅t]

In [225]: type(_222)                                                                                 
Out[225]: sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix

In [227]: ImmutableDenseNDimArray(v2)                                                                
Out[227]: [[t  2⋅t  3⋅t  4⋅t  5⋅t]]

In [228]: type(_)                                                                                    
Out[228]: sympy.tensor.array.dense_ndim_array.ImmutableDenseNDimArray
```

Neither of these has an `as_poly` method, but `integrate` might be doing some further processing.  `numpy` has one main class, `ndarray`, with a well known set of methods and attributes.  `sympy` defines many more classes, so we (I) need to pay a lot more attention to the docs.  The class hierarchy of these two classes (`type(...).__mro__`) is totally different.

---

With `Matrix` the integrate runs and produces:

```
In [235]: integrate(Matrix(v2),t)                                                                    
Out[235]: 
⎡ 2         2           2⎤
⎢t    2  3⋅t      2  5⋅t ⎥
⎢──  t   ────  2⋅t   ────⎥
⎣2        2           2  ⎦
```

It would have been nice (polite!) if you'd provided this output.

And for the case that doesn't work, the FULL traceback might instructive:

```
In [236]: integrate(ImmutableDenseNDimArray(v2),t)                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-236-fbba47abf5a1> in <module>
----> 1 integrate(ImmutableDenseNDimArray(v2),t)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py in integrate(*args, **kwargs)
   1543 
   1544     if isinstance(integral, Integral):
-> 1545         return integral.doit(**doit_flags)
   1546     else:
   1547         new_args = [a.doit(**doit_flags) if isinstance(a, Integral) else a

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py in doit(self, **hints)
    592                 else:
    593                     antideriv = self._eval_integral(
--> 594                         function, xab[0], **eval_kwargs)
    595                     if antideriv is None and meijerg is True:
    596                         ret = try_meijerg(function, xab)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py in _eval_integral(self, f, x, meijerg, risch, manual, heurisch, conds)
    921 
    922         # try to convert to poly(x) and then integrate if successful (fast)
--> 923         poly = f.as_poly(x)
    924         if poly is not None and not (manual or meijerg or risch):
    925             return poly.integrate().as_expr()

AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_poly'
```

We need to dig into this code (that 922 line) to find out why it's trying `f.as_poly`.  Did it also try that with `Matrix`, or did it take a different route?  There's a lot going on in `sympy` code like this!

---

You didn't need to use `np.array` in the first place.  Stick with `sympy`:

```
In [249]: integrate(Matrix([[1,2,3,4,5]])*t,t)                                                       
Out[249]: 
⎡ 2         2           2⎤
⎢t    2  3⋅t      2  5⋅t ⎥
⎢──  t   ────  2⋅t   ────⎥
⎣2        2           2  ⎦
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue is I am shifting from Matlab to python and I am used to working with arrays (only one type of them) to do all my code without the necessity of look after about problems like this.

Comment: Let me ask you then, is it a good idea to make this shift?

Comment: MATLAB didn't have symbolic stuff when I used it years ago (I used MAPLE and MacSyma for that), but in MATLAB matrices (2d and up) are the core structure.  `sympy` is built on python, not `numpy`.  The symbolic package for Octave (free MATLAB) is based on `sympy`, so that might be a better bridge.  But I don't know the details.